# why django returns me a template Error for this case {% if user.is_authenticated %}?

Tags: python, django

i would like to add on my django template main page interface a condition but it return me this error :

ProgrammingError at /

relation "django_session" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ession_data", "django_session"."expire_date" FROM "django_se...

ther is the Template code :

...

```
{% extends '_base.html' %}

{% block title %}Home Page{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>Homepage</h2>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <p>Hi {{ user.email }}</p>
    {% else %}
        <p>You are not Loged</p>
        <p><a href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a> </p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

...
thamk you for your answers

Comment: make sure ```    'django.contrib.sessions'``` in settings.py then,```python manage.py makemigrations sessions``` and ```python manage.py migrate sessions```

Answer (score 1):

You have not migrated your models to the database.

If you have created a custom user class, run the below command for creating the [migration file](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/migrations/#migration-files).

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

If you have already run the migrations, you need to run the [migrate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-migrate) commands so as to convert the migration files into the database schema.

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Hopefully, that will solve your problem